# How to use a custom theme in Vue-Echarts

Tags: vue.js, charts, echarts

I am working with Vue 3 (Composition API) and using 'ecomfe/vue-echarts' to display my data. I copied the example from the documentation and it worked perfectly. The only thing I don't get working is my custom theme:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-chart :theme="themeObj.theme" :option="option" style="height: 95vh"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {use} from 'echarts/core';
import {SVGRenderer} from 'echarts/renderers';
import {LineChart} from 'echarts/charts';
import {TitleComponent, TooltipComponent, LegendComponent, GridComponent} from 'echarts/components';
import VChart from 'vue-echarts';
import "echarts";
import {provide, ref} from 'vue';
import themeObj from '/src/css/echarts-themes/purple-passion.project.json'

use([SVGRenderer, LineChart, TitleComponent, TooltipComponent, LegendComponent, GridComponent]);

const option = ref({
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked Line',
    subtext: 'Access through mediatype per weekday'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Email', 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Email',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [120, 132, 101, 134, 90, 230, 210]
    },
    {
      name: 'Union Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [220, 182, 191, 234, 290, 330, 310]
    },
    {
      name: 'Video Ads',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [150, 232, 201, 154, 190, 330, 410]
    },
    {
      name: 'Direct',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [320, 332, 301, 334, 390, 330, 320]
    },
    {
      name: 'Search Engine',
      type: 'line',
      stack: 'Total',
      data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320]
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

This is a short snippet of my custom JSON-Theme:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "themeName": "purple-passion",
    "theme": {
        "seriesCnt": "3",
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(91,92,110,1)",
        "titleColor": "#ffffff",
        "subtitleColor": "#cccccc",
        "textColorShow": false,
        "textColor": "#333",
        "markTextColor": "#eeeeee",
        "color": [
            "#9b8bba",
            "#e098c7",
            "#8fd3e8",
            "#71669e",
            "#cc70af",
            "#7cb4cc"
        ],
        "borderColor": "#ccc",
        "borderWidth": 0,
        "visualMapColor": [
            "#8a7ca8",
```

The problem I have is, that my custom theme don't get 100% applied: The Background Color changes to rgba(91,92,110,1), but the title color still remains the same and don't change to white (#ffffff).

[image: Output Frontend]

I know (!): You can change the title color through the option object like this:

```
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked Line',
    textStyle: {
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    subtext: 'Access through mediatype per weekday'
  },
```

But I think this is not supposed to be like this, because why do we have the 'titleColor' attribute in the theme object then?

I hope you guys have some solutions to this.

Greetings :)